# Gulp sass build removing 0 before decimal

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, libsass

I am new to GULP sass build structure and I am facing an issue. When I run my gulp process
The final css that is generated has the following things 0 is getting removed before the decimal and line breaks are coming.

Some people are using PC and some are using MAC. In MAC this change is not happening. So every time when we do a git diff the mac code and windows code are different.

```
padding: 0.3em is converted to padding: .3em;

.element, .element2 is converted to 
.element,
.element 2
```

Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: `0.3em` and `.3em` are the same, and `\n' was added, to make code easier to read

Comment: Yes. But the mac gulp process isn't generating the code like this

Comment: maybe MAC and PC are not the same things? Maybe gulp have different properties there :)

Comment: Hmm..Yes can you guide me like where I can configure these properties?

Comment: Try running `npm update` on both operating systems, see if any new updates to packages came out. That could cause issues like this.

Comment: no, i don't use sass and gulp, but you can read about it on gulps website, I think you will find some unswer there :)

Comment: Ok thanks guys.. I will check it out and Update If i find any new things

Comment: Sass isn't a node package so `npm update` won't help. You want to do `gem update sass` on all build machines. The `0` is dropped to reduce file size. The `\n` is added because gulp defaults sass to development environment. There should be no space added between the `2` and `.element`. Did you make a mistake in your example?

Comment: Sass has an option `--precision` to control decimal places. The default is **5** but that doesn't change the `0` being dropped.

Comment: This seems like something that should be raised on the appropriate bug tracker.

Comment: It sounds like you're committing compiled files to your repository which is a no-no. Generally you only want to commit source files. Committing build files is duplicating content and creating unnecessarily busy diffs/commits/pull requests.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia: Yes that was a typo

Comment: @graygilmore: Yes exactly. Thats what I am trying to tell my team. Build file is something that shouldn't be checked in. I am new to the team so it will take some time for me to convince them I guess